# PHP charting library

Tags: php, charts

I'm looking for a PHP chart library, with a few specific criteria:

- I can't use Google charts because, in at least one case, I need to be able to run on a private network with no internet access (ergo no Google).
- I need to be able to produce bitmapped images (png, etc).  SVG would also be nice, and Flash is acceptable as an extra, but the static bitmapped images are necessary (so a completely Flash chart would be unusable).
- Open source preferred but commercial is acceptable.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156252/free-chart-libraries-for-php and see if any of those suggested are suitable.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at:

- [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/)
- [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion in PHP in addition to the already mentioned:

[Topnew SVG Chart 5.5](http://topnew.net/chart/) or [bChart - a simple PHP chart](http://topnew.net/chart/bchart/) for older versions.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: It seems that this answers an off topic question, which is not recommended as of [help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

Try this new stuff:
http://www.highcharts.com/ written in javascript

Comment: Author need of: «I need to be able to produce bitmapped images (png, etc)»
Highcharts can't do that because of client side render.

Answer (score -3):

I would recomment [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) - it's a client-side (javascript) charting library, but it does not requite an internet connection (you can host everything on the intranet). If you want a PHP wrapper for it, many frameworks come with it - for example, here's one for QCubed, the framework that I use: http://examples.qcu.be/assets/plugins/QFlot/example/qflot-timeseries.php

Comment: Author need of: «I need to be able to produce bitmapped images (png, etc)»
Flot can't do that because of client side render.

Answer (score -3):

Try:

- [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/)
- [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

Comment: Author need of: «I need to be able to produce bitmapped images (png, etc)»
These libs can't do that because of client side render.